# JPA EntityManagerFactory

Tags: jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I use jpa in my project. But I must call all method and ever connect to database. I want to connect once database with entitymanagerfactory and other method want used. I made static entitymanagerfactory and entitymanager therefore ı take a error which is transaction is active.

how to make public connect with jpa?

Comment: Use JTA instead of resource local.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspect there will be other issues later on I would suggest you follow [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SettingUpJPA/SettingUpJPA.htm) that show how to make a Java SE JPA application.  A more complete basic tutorial [here](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/persistence/persistence-example.html) is quite focused on Sun's own toolset and components, but the underlying basics and sample code may help you.

Anyways, the start looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnitName");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    // let's start a transaction, everything we do from here on can be either
    // committed or rolled back, ensuring the integrity of our data
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    // update the database here


    // okay, done
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    // and housekeeping, close em an emf
    em.close();
    emf.close();
```

}

As you can see, neither em nor emf have to be static.  If you (as you should) subdivide your project in objects you can pass on the `em` to these objects that will use it to interact with the database.  Also, you're not limited to having just one big transaction that spans the entire lifecycle of the application, you can have several consecutive ones.

Comment: OK. I solved with if(!em.gettransaction.isActive()). thanks for help